# How to use NSScanner or componentsSeperatedByString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a {"Red","Blue","Green","Yellow"} returned as string. How to process this to add to an array ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString* sampleString = @"{\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Green\",\"Yellow\"}";
    NSArray* components = [sampleString componentsSeperatedByString:@"\"{"];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Updated Code#

```
NSString* sampleString = @"{\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Green\",\"Yellow\"}";

NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

// Get newline character set
NSMutableCharacterSet *removeCharacterSet = (id)[NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"{(,}"];
[removeCharacterSet formIntersectionWithCharacterSet:[[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] invertedSet]];

// Characters that are important to the parser
NSMutableCharacterSet *importantCharactersSet = (id)[NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""];
[importantCharactersSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:removeCharacterSet];

// Create scanner, and scan string
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sampleString];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
while ( ![scanner isAtEnd] ) 
{        
    BOOL insideQuotes = NO;
    BOOL finishedRow = NO;
    NSMutableArray *columns = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    NSMutableString *currentColumn = [NSMutableString string];
    while ( !finishedRow ) 
    {
        NSString *tempString;
        if ( [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:importantCharactersSet intoString:&tempString] ) {
            [currentColumn appendString:tempString];
        }

        if ( [scanner isAtEnd] ) {
            if ( ![currentColumn isEqualToString:@""] ) [columns addObject:currentColumn];
            finishedRow = YES;
        }
        else if ( [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:removeCharacterSet intoString:&tempString] ) {
            if ( insideQuotes ) {
                // Add line break to column text
                [currentColumn appendString:tempString];
            }
            else {
                // End of row
                if ( ![currentColumn isEqualToString:@""] ) [columns addObject:currentColumn];
                finishedRow = YES;
            }
        }
        else if ( [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL] ) {
            if ( insideQuotes && [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL] ) {
                // Replace double quotes with a single quote in the column string.
                [currentColumn appendString:@"\""]; 
            }
            else {
                // Start or end of a quoted string.
                insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
            }
        }
        else if ( [scanner scanString:@"," intoString:NULL] ) {  
            if ( insideQuotes ) {
                [currentColumn appendString:@","];
            }
            else {
                // This is a column separating comma
                [columns addObject:currentColumn];
                currentColumn = [NSMutableString string];
                [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] intoString:NULL];
            }
        }
    }
    if ( [columns count] > 0 ) [rows addObject:columns];
}
NSLog(@"This String:%@",[rows objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I got code from http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data. Now the output is This String:( Red ), How to get rid of "(" ")" ?

Comment: Is it part of a larger format, or could it be presented differently, or could there be other types/structures of data there?

Comment: It is not part of larger format. I am currently learning on how to use NSString class, so this would be an example to learn on how to use NSScanner and componentsSeperatedByString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's all you need to scan the sample you've provided using an instance of `NSScanner`:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"{\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Green\",\"Yellow\"}"];
NSMutableCharacterSet *charactersToSkip = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:charactersToSkip]; 
NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *substring = @"";
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charactersToSkip intoString:&substring];
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:charactersToSkip intoString:NULL];
    [substrings addObject:substring];
}

NSLog(@"%@", substrings);
```

Note that if you substituted parens for curly braces, all you'd need to do to create an array of strings from the sample would be:

```
NSString *sampleString = @"(\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Green\",\"Yellow\")";
NSArray *strings = [sampleString propertyList];
NSLog(@"%@", strings);
```

...but I'm not really clear on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: It looks like he's just messing around at this point - no one would ever create and parse a string for four hard-coded colors, lol.

Comment: I'm assuming that's just a smaller sample of larger strings his app will be dealing with, but my real question is how much more complex might the contents of the actual strings be in real life? To be fair, it sounded as though in an earlier comment he was saying he's primarily interested in exploring the APIs at this point rather than solving a particular problem.

Comment: Thanks jlehr.I would accept this as an answer. For complex strings the updated code in my question would work right ? But have you looked at that code where it is adding extra ( and ) ... can you/someone explain that as well like where that (,) are coming from

Comment: If you're exploring APIs, NSScanner isn't worth it. Parse XML with XpathQuery and do JSON with YAJL-Objc. They're so much easier.

Comment: @Aurum, Thanks for your suggestions. Currently I am interested in CSV parsing. But in future I now know what to look for if I come across XML or JSON